# Ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in

Tags: php, xml

```
<root>
  <has_next>True</has_next>
  <next>
    http://rutube.ru
  </next>
  <previous/>
  <page>1</page>
  <per_page>12</per_page>
  <results>
   <list-item>
    <description>
      Озвучено и пере...
```

Разбираю на PHP вот так:

```
echo $xml->results[0]->list-item[0]->description;
```

Вижу такую ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `'['`, expecting `','` or `';'` in D:\SERVER\domains\home.ru\index.php on line 7

В чем проблема? Я же все верно сделал, по XML тегам. А получаю ошибку.

Comment: @totorro, Это не кусок это начало XML,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo $xml->results[0]->{'list-item'}[0]->description;
```

Comment: Ок, работает. А я все думал как эту форму правильно записать) 
list-item